# Email delivery exceptions in Symfony3

Tags: symfony, redirect, config, mailer, email-delivery

I have a Symfony project, that is now being tested on live system, and I'm using the delivery_address to prevent sending email to real recipients.

I needed also some exceptions for this, so I have used a very nice `delivery_whitelist` option ([like here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/dev_environment.html#sending-to-a-specified-address-but-with-exceptions)).

Right now, the white-listed emails are going both to original target and to `delivery_address`, but I'd like them to get sent **only** to the original, white-listed address.
Is that possible in some way?

Comment: Since your requirements exactly contradict the semantics of the configuration options, your only option seems to be adding some logic to your mail sending component. I am sure that you will be able to extract the whitelist and other options programatically so you can build your edge case.

Comment: Looks like that. But I wouldn't say it "exactly contradicts" the original intention of the config option (at least not the official docs). Actually I was expecting exactly what I needed, after having read the docs: "you may want email sent to some specific email addresses to go through after all, *and not be redirected* (even if it is in the dev environment). This can be done by adding the delivery_whitelist option...".
But apparently, it actually **does** get redirected (besides being sent to original address).

Comment: @Joshua: since there seems to be no solution for this case I need, if you'd like to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it officially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @userfuser suggested, here is my slightly altered comment as an answer:

Since your requirement contradicts the semantics of the configuration options, your only option seems to be adding some logic to your mail sending component. I am sure that you will be able to extract the white list and other options programatically so you can build your edge case.